# Taking components of component velocity vectors

Tags: rotational-dynamics, vectors

I was solving a question from the chapter Rigid Body Dynamics, and there was a numerical that said:A flat rigid body is moving in x – y plane on a table. The body lies in the x – y plane . At an instant it was found that some of the velocity components of its three particles A, B and C were $V_{Ax}$ = 4 m/s, $V_{Bx}$ = 3 m/s and $V_{Cy}$ = -2 m/s,

[image: 1]

At that instant, the three were located at (0,0) (3,4) and (4,3) respectively. It was told to find the individual velocities.

[image: 2]
[image: 3]

Now here is where I am a little confused! the step that they did was because the velocity of any two points along the rigid body should be the same along the line joining them. This is very clear. My actual doubt is not related to the dynamics but just how exactly did the author take the components of the components, along the line joining them? I mean isn't taking components of components of velocities and force not allowed? What is the logic behind this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In reality best to write $\vec{v}=v_x\vec{e_x}+v_y\vec{e_y}$ and of cause you can split $\vec{e_x}$ in any two directions